# Facebook SDK: Access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'd like to get an access token without user login.

Standard way is that the user logs in and gets an access token.

But I need the access token to view events of an official page. When I try without access token, the Graph API gives me the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 104
    }

}
```

So my question: Is there any way to get an access token without explicitly logging in or is there maybe another way to get event information without access token?

Thanks so far :)

Comment: `I'd like to get an access token without user login.` - NOT possible
`is there maybe another way to get event information without access token` - NOT possible

Comment: But if your app have the power (permission) to access the user's events, you can use the app's access token to get the events of that particular user.

Comment: Its not for user events! It's an official page (not profile, sorry) where I want to get the event information from

Comment: @Shadowfax Can you give me an example how to get an event info with the app's access token? :)

Comment: Posted the answer. pl check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `never-expiring-access-token` for your page and use that with your call. (without explicitly logging, since you are the admin of the page). Follow the 2 steps: get the extended user (admin) token and then the never expiring page token

1. **Extending the user's access token**

   You can exchange the user's access token with the `long-lived` access token (2-months) validity. Go though the link to get the long-lived token.

   [Extending tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)
2. **Extending the page's access token**

   Make the following call using the `long-lived user's access token` and permission: `manage_pages` you obtained in the above step-

   ```
   $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
   ```

   You'll get the never-expiring-page-token with this.
   (You can use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the validity of the token)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) this websites talks all about Acess Tokens